# Pandas - create rows for entry in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a returned datastructure that I want to explode into multiple rows.

For Example:

```
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data = [1,['X','Y', 'Z'], 23]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

This gives me 3 rows where one column is a list object.

I want to explode the row into 3 rows based on the column `B`. To get the r esult:

```
A    B    C
1    X    23
1    Y    23
1    Z    23
```

Is there a built in command to do this or a method out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
In [114]: pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(columns, data)))
Out[114]:
   A  B   C
0  1  X  23
1  1  Y  23
2  1  Z  23
```